# SSRS: Calculating the average (mean) in a table missing values instead of zeros

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to calculate the average of six machines in the following table.

[image]

The **first column** represents the **machines**, the **second column** is the **good pieces** and the **third column** is **performance**.

In the last row I want to calculate the average (the mean) of the rows but the result is not correct here. It should be 33,6%.

This is the expression I used:

```
=iif(AVG(Fields!Oee.Value)=0, "-", AVG(Fields!Oee.Value))
```

How can I calculate this without zeros?

Comment: http://salvoz.com/blog/2011/11/25/ssrs-checking-for-divide-by-zero-using-custom-code/

Comment: possible dublicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005747/average-of-all-values-except-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the calculation you need to divide the sum of the column with the count of non zero rows

```
= SUM(Fields!Fields!Oee.Value)/ SUM(Iif(Fields!Fields!Oee.Value=0,0,1))
```

Also if you want to output something else for zero values you can use formatting eg. `0,0;-0,0;"-"` (first part is for positive numbers, second for negative and third for zero)

Comment: Thank you, it works. But how can I do it with this formatting? `=Format(SUM(Fields!Oee.Value)/ SUM(Iif(Fields!Oee.Value=0,0,1)),"-")` ?

Comment: In each textbox there is a format property. You set the value to something like the one I suggested. Read more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/el-gr/library/fbxft59x.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

I used the filter option:

[image]

But now in the tablix you can see only the machines which run.

[image]